# How do I make an li change colour when active?

Tags: html, css, filter, nav, reactjs

I am creating an FAQ section on my website where you should be able to filter questions by clicking on one of the section topics. I have this functioning however what I want is for when one of the section titles is selected, that specific title should change from being red to black and underlined. When the mouse is being held down it works but as soon as I let go it changes back. How do I get this to remain in this state when that certain section is active?

CSS:

```
#portfolio .portfolio-list .nav li {
 margin: 0 40px 0 0;
 float: left;
 color: #C42B32;
 line-height: 16px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 600 ! important;
 font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif ! important;
 letter-spacing: 0.02em;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-list .nav li:hover, #portfolio .portfolio-list .nav li.filter-active {
 color: #000000;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s; }

#portfolio .portfolio-list .nav li:active, li:focus, li:focus-within {
color: #000000 ! important;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Titles:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Filters extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="portfolio-list">
                <ul className="nav list-unstyled" id="portfolio-flters">
                    <li className="faqnav" data-item="all" onClick={this.props.filter}>All</li>
                    <li className="faqnav" data-item="general" onClick={this.props.filter}>General</li>
                    <li className="faqnav" data-item="stats" onClick={this.props.filter}>Stats</li>
                    <li className="faqnav" data-item="account" onClick={this.props.filter}>Account</li>
                    <li className="faqnav" data-item="social" onClick={this.props.filter}>Social Media</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}[![Screenshot][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:
    import React from 'react';

```
export default class Filters extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    state = {
        activeFilter: 0,
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="portfolio-list">
                <ul className="nav list-unstyled" id="portfolio-flters">
                    <li className={`faqnav ${this.state.activeFilter === 1 ? 'active': ''}`}  data-item="all" onClick={(e) => this.filter(e, 1)}>All</li>
                    <li className={`faqnav ${this.state.activeFilter === 2 ? 'active': ''}`}  data-item="general" onClick={(e) => this.filter(e, 2)}>General</li>
                    <li className={`faqnav ${this.state.activeFilter === 3 ? 'active': ''}`}  data-item="stats" onClick={(e) => this.filter(e, 3)}>Stats</li>
                    <li className={`faqnav ${this.state.activeFilter === 4 ? 'active': ''}`}  data-item="account" onClick={(e) => this.filter(e, 4)}>Account</li>
                    <li className={`faqnav ${this.state.activeFilter === 5 ? 'active': ''}`}  data-item="social" onClick={(e) => this.filter(e, 5)}>Social Media</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

    filter = (e, filterId) => {
        this.setState({
            activeFilter: filterId,
        });
        this.props.filter(e);
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.faqnav.active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Explanation:
Add a local state, that saves the currently active filter. To each filter, assign some kind of ID, I suggest you to do that with constants. After that, every time a filter is clicked, save the clicked filter id in the state and execute your regular onClick handler. Then add a check in each `<li>` for the currently active filter and add an active class.

Hope that helps.

Comment: When I use that code above and then select one of the filters I get a 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined' along with 'anonymous function)
src/components/Faqquestions2.js:23
  20 | let filteredItems = [];
  21 | 
  22 | this.state.items.forEach(function(item) {
> 23 |   if (item.tags.includes(event.target.dataset.item)) {
     | ^  24 |     filteredItems.push(item);
  25 |   }
  26 | });'

Comment: I updated the answer. I didn't know that you are using the event parameter, because you did not present the original filter() function, coming through props. Please try the new solution.

Comment: Perfect that works! The only thing that doesn't change now though is the colour? The underline stays but the colour returns to red instead of staying black...

Comment: If needed, add more specifications to the CSS class that I presented by adding all classes that you have listed, because your previous styles probably overwrote my code. Also make sure, the class I presented is placed after your classes. If this still doesn't work, try adding `!important `(which is not so bad in this case, because active classes are used to override the regular class style).

Comment: That's great thanks so much for your help I really appreciate it! <3